# Why is my program faster than the one using a python built in function?

Tags: python, list, time

Ok so, I was doing a puzzle on coderbyte, and here is what the puzzle stated:

Have the function SimpleMode(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the number that appears most frequently (the mode). For example: if arr contains [10, 4, 5, 2, 4] the output should be 4. If there is more than one mode return the one that appeared in the array first (ie. [5, 10, 10, 6, 5] should return 5 because it appeared first). If there is no mode return -1. The array will not be empty.

So here is my program:

```
import time
from random import randrange

def SimpleMode(arr): 
  bestMode=0
  numTimes=0
  for x in range(len(arr)):
    if len(arr)>0:
      currentNum=arr[0]
      currentMode=0
      while currentNum in arr:
        currentMode+=1
        arr.remove(currentNum)
      if currentMode>numTimes:
        numTimes=currentMode
        bestMode=currentNum
    else: break
  if numTimes==1: bestMode=-1
  return bestMode

start_time = time.time()
numbers = [randrange(1,10) for x in range(0, 1000)]
print(SimpleMode(numbers))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And here is a much simpler program which someone else wrote:

```
import time
from random import randrange

def SimpleMode(arr): 

  best = -1
  best_count = 1

  for c in arr:
    if arr.count(c) > best_count:
      best = c
      best_count = arr.count(c)

  return best

start_time = time.time()
numbers = [randrange(1,10) for x in range(0, 1000)]
print(SimpleMode(numbers))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Now I know that using my method of timing this it depends on what my CPU is doing and whatnot so this is not the most accurate way, but leaving that aside what I found was that my computer took 0.012000 seconds to run my program, yet it took 0.025001 seconds to run the second program.

Now here is where I am puzzled. My program which I have written myself takes less than half the time the other program takes which uses a built-in python function and has only one for-loop whereas my program has a while loop inside a for-loop.

Can anyone provide any insight into this?

Comment: Just because something uses a built in function doesn't mean it'll be faster if it uses a poorer algorithm.

Comment: As a first guess, your loop takes less iterations, because you remove the elements that are already counted, thus `len(arr) > 0` will likely be true before you've iterated through the complete array. The second algorithm iterates through the full array no matter what, so depending on the array, one algorithm can beat the other way. Have you tried with an array like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]`?

Comment: @Amber Where can I find the algorithm which count() uses?

Comment: @Evert Yes, the original list I used was numbers = [x for x in range(0, 1000)]  and the result was the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second program calls `count` twice each iteration, and since `count` is O(n) (that is, it has to walk through the entire array, just like a for loop would), the time quickly adds up.

That said, your program can be reduced even further:

```
import collections

def SimpleMode(arr):
    if not arr:
        return -1
    counts = collections.Counter(arr)
    return max(counts, key=lambda k: (counts[k], -arr.index(k)))
```

In addition, note that your initial program mutates its input (it effectively destroys the list you pass it because of the `.remove` calls, which will suck if you wanted to do anything with `arr` after calling `SimpleMode`).

And finally, in Python the `[1, 2, 3, 4]` construct is called a list, not an array. There exists something called an array in Python, and it's *not* this (most of the time it's a NumPy array, but it can also be an array from the `array` module in the stdlib).

Comment: Oh I see. He could have just calculated count(c) once in the for-loop, set it to a variable, and then used the variable. Thanks! Also not sure how lambda works but I will look into it.

Comment: Lambdas are just anonymous functions. The trick to my program is in how the `key` argument to `max` works (which is the same as `sort`'s -- look into https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

Comment: Yeah I know it is called a list, it is just that http://www.coderbyte.com/ offers the challenges in six different languages and in most of the languages it is called an array. Although it will probably be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes everything in a single pass.
The other code contains hidden nested loops in the `arr.count()`.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP's code also includes hidden loops in `currentNum in arr` and in `arr.remove()` but the `arr.remove()` is making the list about 100 items shorter each time through, which is perhaps having the greater effect.